# Is this the correct way to implement middleware in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am attempting to debug a redux store for async actions. But I am failing to pass dispatch as a function so I will be posting series of questions to help myself find my issue. The first thing I need to ensure is that I am applying redux-thunk properly. So is this the correct way to implement redux middleware?

```js
import { createStore,applyMiddleware,combineReducers,compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import {inventoryFilter,availableAttributes} from '../reducers/reducer';

const logger=createLogger()

const Store = createStore(

///combine imported reducers
 combineReducers({
    activeFilter:inventoryFilter,
    availableAttributes:availableAttributes

},{},applyMiddleware(thunk,logger)


));



export default Store;
```

Comment: Looks okay to `createStore` this way, but seems have nothing to do w/ the **implementation** of redux middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You're passing the middleware enhancer as an argument to `combineReducers`, when it should actually be an argument to `createStore`.

Here's how I would write it:

```
import { createStore,applyMiddleware,combineReducers,compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import {inventoryFilter,availableAttributes} from '../reducers/reducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    activeFilter:inventoryFilter,
    availableAttributes:availableAttributes
});

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, middlewareEnhancer);

export default store;
```

Comment: Yeah it was one of those semi colon moments. I ended up fixing it by just re-doing everything in a fresh app that worked and just replaced every part. Didn't know the answer so I didn't think it was fair to mark it as answered. but thank you.